# how to display dynamic messages in messagebox using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have created a tool for my functionalities using powershell, i want to update few of my files in my machine locally before launching my tool. i have added below message box to display that files are getting updated loacally. when i click on my tool the below messages should display dynamicaly in the message box.

```
 [system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show("updating file1", "message") 
 [system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show("updating file2", "message") 
 [system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show("updating file3", "message") 
 [system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show("updating file4", "message") 
 [system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show("updating file5", "message")
```

for this it is displaying 5 different message box and i should click on OK on each message box. i want to load these messages dynamically in a single message box. could you please help in resolving it?

Comment: You will not be able to build the thing you asking for with just MessageBox control element. You should be looking for general form that contains label, that will change upon performing steps.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$message = @("updating file1")
$message+="updating file 2"
[system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show(($message -join "`n"), "message")
```

Comment: this looks good, but what i am expecting is the messages should load dynamically after i see the first message

Comment: @PraveenJakkaraju - What do you mean by that?

Comment: Message box should be displayed first with the first message then the first message should disappear and second message should be displayed in the same message box and it should continue till 5th message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the Notify option in Powershell forms. Use the below code for  it .

```
   [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon 

$objNotifyIcon.Icon = "C:\Scripts\Forms\Folder.ico"
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = "Error" 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "A file needed to complete the operation could not be found." 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "File Not Found"

$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True 
$objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
```

Let me know if it works or require more details on this.

Vishnu Gupthan